# validateField doesn't work with models

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

I want to use validateField with models but it says **Method is not defined for this object**!

I code like this:

```
$user_payment=$this->add("Model_Payment");
$user_payment->getField("amount")
                    ->validateNotNull()
                    ->validateField('($this->get())<=0','Please enter a posetive number!');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to apply ->validateNotNull() to Model.
This method should be applied to Field of a Form
Like:

```
$f = $this->add('Form);
$f->setModel('Model_YourModel');

$f->getField("amount")
                ->validateNotNull()....
```

Comment: thanks but now I have another problem! I have same error for this code: $mwform=$mwr->add("Form"); $mwform->addField("Line","mwamount","Amount")->setFieldHint('Unit is $...');
            $mwform->getField("mwamount")
                ->validateNotNull()
                ->validateField('($this->get())!=20','Please enter a posetive number!');
            $mwform->addSubmit("submit");

Comment: What $mwr is? Usually we use $this->add('Form'); Or you can insert your form into the view like:
$v = $this->add('View');
$f = $v->add('Form');
and so on

Comment: OH, and for the Form class use **->getElement();**

I like to use it through variable luke:
    '$f = $this->add('Form')
    $ff = $f->addField('...');

    $ff->validateNotNull();'
It looks more nice for me but it's not required

Answer (score 2):

There is no method getField() in Model_Table class.

You can call this method in Form olny

```
$f = $this->add('Form');
$f->setModel('Model_Payment');
$f->getField("amount")
       ->validateNotNull()
       ->validateField('($this->get())<=0','Please enter a posetive number!');
```

Check source of this method https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/master/lib/Form/Field.php#L235